# In SP Online, does a custom HTML webpart work with with CSS and scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sharepoint-online, web-parts

My company is switching from SharePoint 2016 to SharePoint Online.

Someone on the tech team here built a custom HTML web part. They think it might only work with JSON.

Does anyone know if would be compatible with custom CSS, XML, and JavaScript (via hidden web parts)?

The team has been testing the custom HTML web part, but has been relying on infrequent contact with MS for more information. Full capabilities have not been verified.

Comment: Is your problem solved? if you still need further assistance, please feel free to post back.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint Online is locked down by default.  You can, however, create SPFx web parts (React-JS) using a program like Visual Studio code.  (Included samples at the bottom)  These web parts are deployed via the "Manage apps" area of the admin section (i.e. https://[your tenant]-admin.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/tenantAppCatalog.aspx).

For us, we needed to do some menu modification, specifically on document libraries, so we created an SPFx web extension that is deployed and attaches to all document libraries with a specific content type.  That web part loads all of our JS, css, and other files when triggered.

SPFx Samples:
https://pnp.github.io/sp-dev-fx-webparts/